# How can I define a Yasnippet for #if AND if?

Tags: yasnippet

I would like to define one snippet for a cc-mode `if` statement and a different one for the preprocessors `#if` statement. I tried just defining those two:

For `if`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name : if (...) { ... }
# key: if
# expand-env: ((yas-also-auto-indent-first-line t))
# --
if ( ${1:condition} ) {
    $0
}
```

For `#if`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: #if
# key: #if
# expand-env: ((yas-wrap-around-region t))
# --
#if ${1:MODULE_NAME}
$0
#endif // $1
```

but when I try to complete `#if`, I get the completion for `if`. Directly calling `M-x yas-insert-snippet` with `#if` as parameter works perfectly...

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: You wrote twice the same snippet in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is understanding the priorities `yasnippet` uses to
determine what snippet it should expand.

If I understand the documentation correctly, this is controlled by the
`yas-key-syntaxes` variable which by default is set to: `("w" "w_" "w_." "w_.()" yas-try-key-from-whitespace)`. This might look rather cryptic if you're not
familiar with Emacs [syntax
classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html), but it should be rather clear from the following description:

`Yasnippet` wants to skip an unknown number of characters backwards to find
keywords to expand, so it tests each of the elements of `yas-key-syntaxes` in
turn, using each combination of characters to determine what characters to skip:

- `w` Skip any piece of text that matches *words*.
- `_` Skip any piece of text that matches *symbols*.
- `.` Skip any piece of text that matches *punctuation*.

In this case, you *can* fix your `#if` snippet by changing the `yas-key-syntax`
priorities to try `"w."` before `"w"` or `"w_"` since *#* belong to the
punctuation syntax class. I.e.,:

```
(setq yas-key-syntaxes '("w." "w" "w_" "w_." "w_.()" yas-try-key-from-whitespace))
```

Personally, I would bind the snippet to a different keyword, such as *pif* (pp for pre-processor) instead, but feel free to try it out.

It might also be useful to check out `M-x` `describe-syntax`, to figure out what
characters belong to which syntax class in a particular major mode.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation :) Since I want to mess with these settings as little as possible, I'll go the way of renaming my #if to something different.

Comment: Actually I am considering reversing the default of order of `yas-key-syntaxes`, which should allow `#if` and `if` keys to work, [see #805](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/805#issuecomment-294523427).

Comment: I thought about it some more, and I actually agree @npostavs. I think it makes sense to try as many characters as possible first and then successively reduce the size rather than the other way around.